# I've moved to a new domain a long time ago but a site:search for the old domain still shows results, can I request removal of those now?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, redirects

My website is located at `example.cc`. Another domain, `example.com`, redirects to it.

I wonder why searching for `site:example.com` yields different results with `site:example.cc`? Shouldn't Google detect that this domain is just a redirection and make a clean up? I moved to the new domain a long time ago.

In Google Search Console, both are domains properties, but the `example.com` property doesn't seem to receive traffic anymore. Is it safe for me to request to remove results in `example.com` without losing my rank?

Comment: How long has it been?

Comment: I don't remember the exact time, but it should be more than three months.

Comment: How did you facilitate the redirect? Is the old domain still active? It seems that the old domain is still being crawled/indexed.

Comment: How do you know that it's still crawled? I use the redirection from the domain provider